# Вырезать текст и вставить в переменные

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
var reg = "Паша, Петя";
```

Как вырезать регулярным выражением 2 слова и добавить их в новые переменные?
Слова могут быть разные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var string = "Паша, Петя, Вова";
names = string.split(', ');
console.log(names[2] + ' красаучиг'); // Вова красаучиг
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень просто, как я и думал))